PDF Text Extraction Order Not Matching Visual Layout Despite Correct Coordinates
I am working on extracting text from a PDF using PyMuPDF. However, I am encountering an issue where the extracted text order does not match the visual flow/Layout flow of the PDF.
Details of the Issue:

The PDF's text is correctly positioned according to its coordinates (bounding boxes), but the logical extraction order is incorrect.
For example, on the first page of my PDF:

After extracting line 2, the tool directly jumps to a table at the bottom of the page, skipping intervening text.
Later, it picks up lines 3–20 in an unordered manner.


I have verified that the issue is not related to column or layout misalignment, as the coordinates are accurate.

What I Have Tried:

I previously posted similar questions here, and the suggested approaches included:
Sorting the extracted text by y (vertical) and x (horizontal) coordinates.
Using tools like PyPDF2, PDFMiner, and Adobe Acrobat for re-tagging.
However, these approaches did not solve the issue, as the extraction tools seem to rely on the internal encoding order of the text objects, which is inherently flawed in my PDF text output.

Additional Information::

I am not looking to perform OCR, as the text is already present in the PDF.
The document contains multi-column layouts and mixed elements like tables and have complex layouts in the PDF.


If you think you've found a bug you should open a bug report. Or go to Discord, the Artifex server, and the #pymupdf channel and ask for help there.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

PyMuPDF by default extracts text in physical sequences as stored in the page appearance source. There are many options available to produce layout fidelity, including table detection / extraction, markdown output generation and more. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

@JorjMcKie , thank you for your suggestions. I have tried the methods you recommended, but unfortunately, the extracted output still follows the same order.
The issue seems to lie in the PDF itself. As I understand it, PDFs store text objects in a sequence defined during their creation, and this sequence often doesn't align with the visual reading order. This inherent mismatch is causing the extraction tools to follow the internal storage order rather than the visual flow.
If you have any additional insights or alternative approaches to handle such PDFs, I would greatly appreciate it.

You may want to submit a problem example to the Discussions and see how more concrete advices may help.
